# sed continuous digit only and remove anything longer and shorter

Tags: linux, sed

i try to extract continuous digit, only with 5 continuous digit, i want to remove all letters, any other digit that is not 5 continuously.

```
echo ajik84928ijs23d8ff89fj | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' > answer.txt
echo ajik84928ijs23d8ff89fj | grep -E -o "[0-9]+"
echo ajik84928ijs23d8ff89fj| tr -d [a-z]
```

i only want 84928, but i can only get 8492823889, i seached many posts but still the closest answer is showed above, thanks for your help. anything such as sed, tr, grep, pearl is going to help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
echo ajik84928ijs23d8ff89fj | sed -r 's/.*([0-9]{5}).*/\1/'
```

With GNU grep:

```
echo ajik84928ijs23d8ff89fj | grep -E -o "[0-9]{5}"
```

Output:

```
84928
```

Comment: thanks for you quick response. i tried on my mac, its an illegal option -r .

Comment: but i tried on my linux , it works, any idea to help my mac?? thanks!

Comment: try `echo "ajik84928ijs23d8ff89fj111111"` . it won't fit *only with 5 continuous digit*. It shouldn't match `111111`

Comment: @RobertChoy: You tagged your question with `linux`.

Comment: @Cyrus yea i think they are 99% same, but somehow they are not in this situation

Comment: @RobertChoy: Try this: `sed 's/.*\([0-9]\{5\}\).*/\1/'`

Comment: -`r` is GNU sed only. `-E` will work with both GNU and OSX sed and so should always be used instead of `-r`. Just tag your question with what you're using so you don't have to worry abut how similar your real system is to the other one you tagged the question with instead.

Answer (score 0):

***grep*** approach to match only 5-digit numbers(not less and not more):

```
echo "ajik84928ijs23d8ff89fj111111123" | grep -Po '(^|[^0-9])\K[0-9]{5}(?=[^0-9]|$)'
84928
```